# SQL Query to designate value based upon finding a value within the previous n-rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a process that records when an event occurs and it is assumed that this event has an influence over the next six hours.

A table has data consisting of Date, Period, BooleanValue; where the Day is dd/mm/yyyy, the Period is a value 1-48 designating the half-hour period (there are 48 during a day) and whether an event has caused a occurred (Impact or NotImpact). As an example, a single event has occurred on 5th Jan 2011 (Period 3) and thus, the table looks like:

```
    Date            Period      Event
    05/01/2011      1           NotImpact
    05/01/2011      2           NotImpact
    05/01/2011      3           IMPACT
    05/01/2011      4           NotImpact
    05/01/2011      5           NotImpact
```

In Excel, I have created forth column and wrote a formula that looks for "IMPACT" in the 'Event' column and if found, flags the next 12 Half Hours as "IMPACT". If it doesn't find "IMPACT", the default value of "NotImpact" is used.

```
 =IF(IF(ISERROR(COUNTIF(E2:E13,"IMPACT")),"NotImpact",COUNTIF(E2:E13,"DIS"))>0,"IMPACT","NotImpact")
```

Applying this formula, to the forth column, would result it:

```
    Date            Period      Event       ImpactYesNo
    05/01/2011      1           NotImpact   NotImpact
    05/01/2011      2           NotImpact   NotImpact
    05/01/2011      3           IMPACT      IMPACT
    05/01/2011      4           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      5           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      6           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      7           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      8           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      9           NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      10          NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      11          NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      12          NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      13          NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      14          NotImpact   IMPACT
    05/01/2011      15          NotImpact   NotImpact
    05/01/2011      16          NotImpact   NotImpact
    05/01/2011      17          NotImpact   NotImpact
```

I would much prefer to have this table generated in SQL (this table is residing on a SQL Server 2005 box) and I have attempted to replicate this Excel approach on there (and writing a function in Python) but with no success. I would really grateful if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction.

If I can answer any other questions about what I am asking, please do not hesitate to pop them in the comments

Comment: Can an event impact across days - ie. if there is an impact in period 47 on 05 Jan 2011, does it impact up to and including period 10 on 06 Jan 2011?

Comment: If it happens in period 15, do you want it to run until period 3 next day? Or cease at end of day?

Comment: (1) An event can run over days and that's quite right Mark
(2) If it happens in Period 15 - the 15th Half Hour of the day - it would run until the 27th Period

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    @Intervals INT, -- How many periods per day 
    @Lasts INT  -- Number of intervals effected
SELECT 
    @Intervals  = 48, 
    @Lasts = 6

-- Use CTE to calculate continous sequence #
;WITH SeqImpact ([Date], Period, [Event], Seq)
AS (Select *, Convert(int, Date) * @Intervals + Period as SEQ  from IMPACT)

SELECT 
    [Date],
    Period,
    [Event], 
    CASE (
            SELECT Count(*) 
            FROM SeqImpact History 
            WHERE 
                History.Seq <= SeqImpact.Seq 
                AND  History.Seq > SeqImpact.Seq - @Lasts 
                AND [Event] = 'Impact'
        )
        WHEN 0 THEN 'NotImpact'
        ELSE 'Impact'
    END
    AS ImpactYesNo 
FROM SeqImpact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It converts your date and period to datetime and then does some calculations on that. You have to test with your data to see if the performance is good enough or not.

```
set dateformat dmy

;with C as
(
  select dateadd(minute, (Period - 1) * 30, cast([Date] as datetime)) as StartTime,
         [Date],
         Period,
         [Event]
  from YourTable
)
select C1.[Date],
       C1.Period,
       C1.[Event],
       coalesce(C2.[Event], C1.[Event]) as ImpactYesNo
from C as C1
  left outer join (select StartTime,
                          dateadd(hour, 6, StartTime) as EndTime,
                          [Event]
                   from C
                   where [Event] = 'IMPACT') as C2
    on C1.StartTime >= C2.StartTime and 
       C1.StartTime < C2.EndTime              
order by C1.StartTime
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122443/

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  [Date] varchar(10),
  Period int,
  [Event] varchar(9)
);

-- shortened to 1 hour periods
insert into @T
select '20110501',      1,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      2,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      3,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      4,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      5,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      6,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      7,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      8,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      9,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      10,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      11,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      12,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      13,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      14,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      15,          'IMPACT' union all
select '20110501',      16,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      17,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      18,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      19,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      20,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      21,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      22,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      23,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110501',      24,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      1,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      2,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      3,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      4,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      5,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      6,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      7,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      8,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      9,           'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      10,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      11,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      12,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      13,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      14,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      15,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      16,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      17,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      18,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      19,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      20,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      21,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      22,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      23,          'NotImpact' union all
select '20110601',      24,          'NotImpact';

with cte as
(
  select [Date], Period, [Event],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date], Period) AS rn
  from @T
)
SELECT
    T1.[Date], T1.Period,
    ISNULL(T2.[Event], T1.[Event]),
T1.rn , T2.rn
FROM
    cte T1
    LEFT JOIN
    cte T2 ON T1.rn BETWEEN T2.rn AND T2.rn + 12 AND T2.[Event] = 'Impact'
```